# I am trying to clip a background div with an SVG text

Tags: css, clip-path

> instead of a curve or circle.
> the span in my example would be the SVG text.
> and it should cut the div at that position

`

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  padding:6rem;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%);
  background-size:20px 20px;
  background-position:0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
}

div {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  background:#c8c8c8;
  border:5px solid #bbb;
  border-radius:20px;
  filter:
    drop-shadow(0  1px  1px hsl(var(--shadow-color, 0deg 0% 0%) / 0.075))
    drop-shadow(0  2px  2px hsl(var(--shadow-color, 0deg 0% 0%) / 0.075))
    drop-shadow(0  4px  4px hsl(var(--shadow-color, 0deg 0% 0%) / 0.075))
    drop-shadow(0  8px  8px hsl(var(--shadow-color, 0deg 0% 0%) / 0.075))
    drop-shadow(0 16px 16px hsl(var(--shadow-color, 0deg 0% 0%) / 0.075));
}
span {
  position:absolute;
  top:-60px;
  right:50px;
  font-size:140px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}
/*I've tried using clip-path and background-clip but I'm not getting the desired result*/
```

```html
<div>
  <span>289</span>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Hi:) It's not clear what the problem is. Could you please provide your HTML/CSS code so we can help you?

Comment: hi, sorry I just did, I'm new to stack overflow UI, I thought I added my code before.

Comment: Okay, and where is the SVG?

Comment: that's the problem I've used online SVG creators to make the text but i couldn't, get it to stay in the position that I wanted so I removed it. please can you help me add an SVG to your solution? it should be in the same position as the span, and the span is to be removed.

Comment: I could make this SVG for you. It should be 289, right? But what font?

Comment: any font, I'll just learn from your solution. I create what I want from your guideline.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a container with a gradient red to yellow and an SVG containing `<clipPath>` tag. Actually this tag makes the mask.

```css
.container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    clip-path: url(#myClip);
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
     
<g>
<clipPath id="myClip">
    <path fill="#EC008C" d="M54.325,138.727h-40.8c1.68-4.398,4.759-9.339,9.24-14.819c4.479-5.479,8.56-10.399,12.24-14.761
        c3.679-4.359,6.759-8.958,9.24-13.799c2.479-4.839,3.72-9.979,3.72-15.42c0-3.12-0.3-5.82-0.9-8.1c-0.6-2.28-1.421-4.099-2.46-5.46
        c-1.041-1.359-2.241-2.379-3.6-3.06c-1.361-0.679-2.88-1.02-4.56-1.02c-2.88,0-5.241,1.121-7.08,3.36
        c-1.841,2.241-2.841,4.881-3,7.92c0.48,2.801,1.119,4.92,1.92,6.36c0.799,1.44,2.359,2.28,4.68,2.52
        c0.24-0.079,0.699-0.24,1.38-0.48c0.679-0.24,1.32-0.439,1.92-0.6c0.6-0.16,1.06-0.24,1.38-0.24c0.799,0,1.2,0.681,1.2,2.04
        c0,2.4-1.2,4.44-3.6,6.12s-4.961,2.601-7.68,2.76c-7.521-0.48-11.721-5.16-12.6-14.04c0.319-6.399,3.039-11.439,8.16-15.12
        c5.119-3.679,10.999-5.52,17.64-5.52c6.799,0,12.619,1.901,17.46,5.7c4.839,3.801,7.5,8.94,7.98,15.42
        c0.559,6.48-0.701,11.682-3.78,15.6c-3.081,3.921-8.48,8.802-16.2,14.64c-7.721,5.842-13.46,10.92-17.22,15.24h25.32l11.52-0.48
        l-4.56,22.08h-3.96l0.24-4.439c0-0.96-0.201-1.602-0.6-1.92C56.564,138.887,55.685,138.727,54.325,138.727z"/>
    <path fill="#EC008C" d="M91.764,100.567c-8.88-5.199-13.481-12.318-13.8-21.36c0.24-2.56,0.559-4.519,0.96-5.88
        c1.519-4.959,4.5-8.82,8.939-11.58c4.44-2.76,9.42-4.219,14.941-4.38c7.277-0.079,13.238,1.68,17.879,5.28
        c4.639,3.6,6.961,7.961,6.961,13.08c-0.24,7.041-4.641,12.641-13.201,16.8c10.16,5.28,15.24,13.122,15.24,23.52
        c0,4.881-1.379,9.18-4.139,12.9c-2.762,3.72-6.322,6.561-10.682,8.52c-4.361,1.959-9.02,2.859-13.979,2.7
        c-7.92-0.239-14.262-2.419-19.021-6.54c-4.76-4.119-6.94-9.3-6.54-15.54C75.883,110.488,81.364,104.646,91.764,100.567z
         M96.205,102.848c-5.441,4.24-8.16,9.959-8.16,17.159c-0.161,4.161,1.158,7.781,3.96,10.86c2.799,3.08,6.72,4.619,11.759,4.619
        c4,0,7.34-1.338,10.02-4.02c2.68-2.68,4.021-5.82,4.021-9.42c0-2.64-0.682-5.02-2.041-7.14c-1.361-2.119-3.102-3.88-5.219-5.28
        c-2.121-1.398-4.361-2.619-6.721-3.66C101.463,104.928,98.923,103.888,96.205,102.848z M95.004,64.207
        c-3.12,1.841-4.842,4.881-5.16,9.12c0.318,2.96,1.519,5.46,3.6,7.5c2.08,2.04,4.72,3.821,7.919,5.34
        c3.199,1.521,6.16,2.88,8.881,4.08c3.439-2.88,5.16-7.2,5.16-12.96c0-2.479-0.541-4.92-1.621-7.32
        c-1.078-2.4-2.68-4.279-4.799-5.64c-2.121-1.359-4.5-2.04-7.141-2.04C99.364,62.287,97.083,62.928,95.004,64.207z"/>
    <path fill="#EC008C" d="M173.842,105.727c-3.359,3.201-7.879,4.92-13.559,5.16c-2.881-0.318-4.842-0.639-5.881-0.959
        c-5.279-1.359-9.299-4.24-12.061-8.641c-2.76-4.399-4.221-9.439-4.379-15.12c-0.08-4.479,0.939-8.958,3.061-13.44
        c2.117-4.479,5.178-8.119,9.18-10.92c3.998-2.799,8.598-4.2,13.799-4.2c9.199,0,16.021,3.521,20.461,10.56
        c4.439,7.041,6.66,16.401,6.66,28.08c0,11.601-2.58,21.86-7.74,30.78c-5.16,8.921-13.182,13.381-24.061,13.381
        c-4.4,0-8.301-0.883-11.699-2.641c-3.402-1.76-5.381-4.48-5.941-8.16c0.16-1.92,0.842-3.541,2.041-4.86s2.719-1.979,4.561-1.979
        c2.078,0,3.617,0.521,4.619,1.56c1,1.04,2.059,2.7,3.18,4.979c1.119,2.28,2.059,3.861,2.82,4.74c0.76,0.881,1.98,1.439,3.66,1.68
        c0.318-0.158,0.721-0.24,1.199-0.24c2.801-0.239,4.92-2.039,6.361-5.399C172.201,125.607,173.441,117.486,173.842,105.727z
         M164.002,104.047c2,0.08,3.881-0.42,5.641-1.5c1.758-1.08,3.16-2.619,4.199-4.62v-17.52c-0.16-5.28-1-9.64-2.52-13.08
        c-1.52-3.439-3.881-5.119-7.08-5.04c-2.879,0.081-4.961,1.32-6.24,3.72c-1.279,2.4-2.039,5.04-2.279,7.92
        c-0.24,2.88-0.359,6.041-0.359,9.48C155.041,97.008,157.922,103.888,164.002,104.047z"/>
</clipPath>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: thanks, Azu. I wanna ask can the clipping be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny addition to Azu's working example code:

In chromium the counter shape inside the nine wont't "cut out".
Pretty sure it is a path direction issue (ideally outer shapes are defined by a clockwise coordinate order – counter shapes use a counter-clockwise direction).
You could replace it with this path:

```
<path id="nine" fill="#EC008C" d="M184.5,68.2c-4.4-7-11.3-10.6-20.5-10.6c-5.2,0-9.8,1.4-13.8,4.2c-4,2.8-7.101,6.4-9.2,10.9
s-3.1,9-3.1,13.4c0.199,5.7,1.6,10.7,4.399,15.1c2.8,4.399,6.8,7.3,12.101,8.6c1,0.3,3,0.601,5.899,1c5.7-0.2,10.2-2,13.601-5.2
c-0.4,11.801-1.601,19.9-3.7,24.4c-1.4,3.4-3.601,5.2-6.4,5.4c-0.5,0-0.899,0.1-1.2,0.199c-1.699-0.199-2.899-0.8-3.699-1.699
c-0.801-0.9-1.7-2.5-2.801-4.7c-1.1-2.3-2.199-3.9-3.199-5c-1-1-2.5-1.601-4.601-1.601c-1.8,0-3.399,0.7-4.6,2
c-1.2,1.301-1.9,2.9-2,4.9c0.6,3.7,2.5,6.4,5.899,8.2c3.4,1.8,7.301,2.6,11.7,2.6c10.9,0,18.9-4.5,24.101-13.399
c5.199-8.9,7.699-19.2,7.699-30.8C191.1,84.6,188.9,75.2,184.5,68.2z M173.8,97.9c-1,2-2.399,3.5-4.2,4.6c-1.8,1.1-3.6,1.6-5.6,1.5
c-6.1-0.2-9-7-8.6-20.6c0-3.4,0.1-6.6,0.399-9.5c0.2-2.9,1-5.5,2.3-7.9c1.301-2.4,3.4-3.6,6.2-3.7c3.2-0.1,5.601,1.6,7.101,5
c1.5,3.4,2.399,7.8,2.5,13.1v17.5H173.8z"/>
```

Be careful about mixing up the terms **mask** and **clipping-path** since both methods exist both in css and in svg.
But they work quite differently and are also differently well supported by browsers.